# Problem authenticating with SharePoint Online when using GetWebLoginClientContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, sharepoint-online, csom

We've got an ASP.NET MVC web application running on Azure on which we want to expose search results from a SharePoint Online tenant. Users in the web app are authenticated on Azure AD, and we want to have them search as themselves (preserving their identity and not use a system account) so that they only see items in the search results that are relevant to them. I thought this would be quite a common requirement.

Using the [SharePointPnPCoreOnline](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline/) CSOM extentions, we were able to retrieve search results with:

```
var authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
ClientContext clientContext = authManager.GetWebLoginClientContext("https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com");
KeywordQuery keywordQuery = new KeywordQuery(clientContext);
keywordQuery.QueryText = "queryText";
SearchExecutor searchExecutor = new SearchExecutor(clientContext);
ClientResult<ResultTableCollection> results = searchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(keywordQuery);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

(The GetWebLoginClientContext method pops a new window which asks for user credentials if they are not already authenticated. Ideally we would like to have it done silently, but this was the only method wa managed to get working.)

During dev everything was working OK - we were getting the expected search results. However, once we published the web app to Azure we got the following error when trying to search:

> 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
> There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

One of the suggestions we found for solving http 502 errors was to clear the browser cache, but after we done so it no longer worked on the dev machine either. Instead of displaying a popup requesting user credentials, the popup now just displays the SharePoint Online tenant home page without any login prompt.

Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Or if not, a better way to have users search SharePoint Online without the popup displayed by the GetWebLoginClientContext method?

Comment: Hi, Seems like the issue is related to the GetWebLoginContext method. I don't think you can use that in Azure Web app. GetWebLoginContext uses FedAuth cookies. In Azure we cant access FedAuth cookies from the Azure Web App as it is related to the COM objects. You might need to go with the App Model.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Not sure what you mean by going with the App Model though. Do you mean something like this: http://jomit.blogspot.com/2013/03/authentication-and-authorization-with.html ?

Comment: Refer the below artcile. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs

Comment: Thanks again for that. But that example is using the GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext method of the PnP extensions, which only gives us an application context. We actually need to get the current logged in user's context.

Comment: Then you can create a app in Azure AD and use the GetAzureADNativeApplicationAuthenticatedContext extension method to get the Client Context. Otherwise we dont have any way to access SharePoint from CSOM. Unless you have to go with the REST,

Comment: Already tried `GetAzureADNativeApplicationAuthenticatedContext` but get the error `An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending` after the user receives a popup to enter his credentials. However, after entering their credentials and clicking back on their browser, they are able to connect to SharePoint. So authentication is working but there are async issues with the method. Tried `ctx.ExecuteQueryAsync()` as well as `ctx.ExecuteQuery()` but without any luck.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this in the end not with the `GetWebLoginClientContext` method (which pops a window for the user to enter credentials) but with the `GetAzureADWebApplicationAuthenticatedContext` method which authenticates silently using an oauth access token. The problem was obtaining the right token to pass to the method, which we succeeded in doing by using `MicrosoftGraphHelper.GetAccessTokenForCurrentUser(url)` found [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Partner-Pack/blob/master/OfficeDevPnP.PartnerPack.SiteProvisioning/OfficeDevPnP.PartnerPack.Infrastructure/MicrosoftGraphHelper.cs)

Comment: Can you share details of how you got it working with MicrosoftGraphHelper.GetAccessTokenForCurrentUser()
Having the same issue

Comment: We used the MicrosoftGraphHelper.GetAccessTokenForCurrentUser(url) as it is in the link above.

Comment: However, the above uses ADAL which is being phased out soon, so depending on your constraints it might not be the best way to go. Microsoft Graph is the current recommended way to access SharePoint Online, and the general availability of the [search connector for MS Graph](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/roadmap?filters=&searchterms=67139) has just been announced

Comment: Thanks. In the end I used an App within sharepoint, details here: https://www.vrdmn.com/2019/01/working-with-application-permissions.html